# does unordered_map::clear() releases the memory occupied by the elements in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have created an unordered_map:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int> > list;
```

1. When I call `list.clear()`, are the elements of the map destroyed?
2. Does the memory occupied by each vector released?

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, `list.clear()` is defined in the standard in terms of destroying the container's elements.
2. If you mean to ask if any memory leaks, then no – all memory is released and none leaks. However, the memory may not necessarily be released back to the OS.